# Do Google Cloud SQL use Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

Do Cloud SQL depend on Compute Engine to run? As I create cloud SQL it's said needed Compute Engine to be created but as I checked for the billing report, the compute engine cost 6-7 times more than cloud SQL.

Is it ok to disable Compute engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/create-instance) depends on the Compute Engine API for the machine type, vCPUs and memory size of your Cloud SQL instance. 
If you will try to disable the Compute Engine API with a Cloud SQL instance deployed, your Cloud SQL instance might not work and can get deleted.